# Does $1-\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1, X_2>x_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2>x_2)$ hold?

Tags: probability

I am wondering does $1-\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1, X_2>x_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2>x_2)$? Even if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent?

Comment: Have you tried moving $\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1, X_2>x_2)$ to the other side of the alleged equality?

Answer (score 2):

No. What if $X_2<x_2$ with probability $1$?

Comment: Or even $X_2\le x_2$ for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a few situations.  We can split the possibilities into four disjoint events:
$$\{X_1>x_1,X_2>x_2\},\qquad \{X_1\leq x_1,X_2>x_2\}, \\ \{X_1>x_1,X_2\leq x_2\}, \qquad \{X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2\}.$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align*} 1=&\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1,X_2>x_2)+\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2>x_2)\\
&+\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1,X_2\leq x_2)+\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2).  
\end{align*}
Rearranging, we obtain
\begin{align*} 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1,X_2>x_2)=\ &\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2>x_2)\\
&+\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1,X_2\leq x_2)\\
&\ +\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2).  
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It only works with conditional probabilities:

$$1-\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1| X_2>x_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1|X_2>x_2)$$

If we assume independence the equation can be written as

$$1-\mathbb{P}(X_1>x_1)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)$$

This looks very familiar to the most.